# Github actions failed to deploy Jekyll website on Github pages

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, github-actions

I have setup a local Jekyll site that is configured to deploy to Github pages. I used the "Chirpy" theme (see https://github.com/cotes2020/jekyll-theme-chirpy) and followed the instructions successfully to get it to deploy the first time.

I am trying to get my 2nd commit w/ updates to deploy but the process is failing when the Github action runs. I see this output:

[image]

This is my first attempt at any of this so don't have any perspective on what is going on w/ any of these technologies.

Thanks for any help and LMK what else might make things clearer!

Comment: If this is public, can you provide us with the GitHub repo? It's easier to inspect the .yml file and look at the logs. Seems like you render/compile the page after switching branch. Maybe switch branch follow-by rendering, then commit and push.

Comment: Awesome - yes you can find it here: https://github.com/frame-lang/frame-lang.github.io

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using the built-in `gh-pages` build for GitHub pages?

Comment: I'm intending to and thought I was still following that process. What do you see that indicates I am not doing it correctly?  As I understand it I check my code into Main and then the Github actions kick in and push a successful build over to gh-pages. I had this work once and then something broke.

Comment: What I mean is that for Jekyll you shouldn't need to provide a .github/workflows.  Anyway, glad you got to to work. Note that you are using `actions/setup-ruby` which is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. As this is my first attempt at using Jekyll I am following the guidance in the theme documenation here: https://github.com/cotes2020/jekyll-theme-chirpy. In the readme it says "For security reasons, GitHub Pages build runs on safe mode, which restricts us from using plugins to generate additional page files. Therefore, we can use GitHub Actions to build the site, store the built site files on a new branch, and use that branch as the source of the GH Pages service." I understand that to mean I need to use a workflow. Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like after you run test.sh, you tried to switch branches. I suspect that is the problem because it doesn't appear that you tried to `git reset` or anything like that. I believe your test.sh ran (see these [lines](https://github.com/frame-lang/frame-lang.github.io/blob/main/tools/test.sh#L62-L67)) so there are unstaged changes.

If you don't want those changes, you might try a `git stash` to easily reset. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was that I checked in the _site and .jekyll-cache directories. Here is the proper .gitignore entries to have the standard gh-pages branch build w/o this problem.

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Jekyll.gitignore